# Gnuplot: plotting the maximum of two files

Tags: max, gnuplot

let's assume I have two files formatted like this:
x      --- y
0      --- 2
1      --- 2.4
2      --- 3.6
which differ for the values of y.
is there a way to plot a single graph that is, for every x, the maximum value of y between the two files?

Dunno if explained my self sufficiently well.

I was trying with conditional sentences but I couldn't find any expression that let me search in 2 different files

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no way to combine two files or more in a single plot with gnuplot only. You must use an external tool to do this, e.g. the command line utility `paste`:

```
max(x, y) = (x > y ? x : y)
plot '< paste fileA.txt fileB.txt' using 1:(max($2, $4))
```

The `y` values are contained in the second and fourth columns.

This next version uses a `python` script with `numpy` to concatenate the files, but any other scripting language would also do:

```py
"""paste.py: merge lines of two files."""
import numpy as np
import sys

if (len(sys.argv) < 3):
    raise RuntimeError('Need two files')

A = np.loadtxt(sys.argv[1])
B = np.loadtxt(sys.argv[2])

np.savetxt(sys.stdout, np.c_[A, B], delimiter='\t')
```

To plot, use:

```
max(x, y) = (x > y ? x : y)
plot '< python paste.py fileA.txt fileB.txt' using 1:(max($2, $4))
```

Comment: Can you provide a platform-idependent solution too?

Comment: @DanielTuzes I thinks it is not possible to do it with gnuplot only, which would be the best way. I added a `python` script, which might be more platform-independent than using `paste`, see the edit.

Comment: @DanielTuzes just for fun... Find some platform-independent gnuplot only versions in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Just for the records, there ***is*** a way with gnuplot ***only*** to get the maximum out of two files.

For sure, it's probably more efficient to use Linux tools or on Windows install, e.g. CoreUtils from [GnuWin](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/coreutils.htm), but with gnuplot-only you are surely platform independent without extra installations.

**Assumption:** both files have same number of lines and identical x-values

***Edit:** simplified code which works for all gnuplot versions>=4.6.0 and faster version for gnuplot>=5.2.0 using an array.*

The simple "trick" is to write the y value of one file into a single string and address them via `word()`. For small data this is ok, but for larger data (>10'000 lines) it might get slow because apparently it runs with something like `O(N^2)`. Just to get an idea (on my system): 1'000 lines take 0.4 seconds, 10'000 lines take 13 seconds and 20'000 lines already take 45 seconds.

As comparison, the array-solution for gnuplot>=5.2.0 just takes about 3 seconds for 10'000 lines.

**Data:**

`SO19079146_1.dat`

```
1   1.1
2   2.1
4   1.5
6   1.3
7   0.2
8   1.5
9   2.1
```

`SO19079146_2.dat`

```
1   2.1
2   2.5
4   1.5
6   0.3
7   0.7
8   1.0
9   1.4
```

**Script 1:** (works for gnuplot>=4.6.0, March 2012)

```
### plot maximum from two files
reset

FILE1 = 'SO19079146_1.dat'
FILE2 = 'SO19079146_2.dat'

data2 = ''
stats FILE2 u (data2=data2.' '.sprintf("%g",$2)) nooutput

set offset 1,1,1,1
max(col) = (i=int(column(0)+1), y1=column(col), y2=real(word(data2,i)), y1>y2 ?  y1 : y2)

plot FILE1 u 1:(max(2)) w lp pt 7 lw 8 lc rgb "grey" ti "Max", \
        '' u 1:2 w lp pt 7 lc rgb "red"  ti "Data1", \
     FILE2 u 1:2 w lp pt 7 lc rgb "blue" ti "Data2"
### end of script
```

**Script 2:** (works for gnuplot>=5.2.0, Sept. 2017)

```
### find the maximum out of two files/datablocks (gnuplot>=5.2.0)
reset session

FILE1 = 'SO/SO19079146_1.dat'
FILE2 = 'SO/SO19079146_2.dat'

stats FILE1 u 0 nooutput
array A[STATS_records]
stats FILE2 u (i=int($0+1), A[i]=$2) nooutput

set offset 1,1,1,1
max(col) = (i=int(column(0)+1), y1=column(col), y2=A[i], y1>y2 ?  y1 : y2)

plot FILE1 u 1:(max(2)) w lp pt 7 lw 8 lc "grey" ti "Max", \
        '' u 1:2 w lp pt 7 lc "red"  ti "Data1", \
     FILE2 u 1:2 w lp pt 7 lc "blue" ti "Data2"
### end of script
```

**Result:** (identical for all above versions)

[image]