# Gnuplot: import x-axis from file

Tags: file, gnuplot, axis

I have two files 'results.dat' and 'grid.dat'.

The results.dat contains per row a different data set of y values.

```
1     325.5   875.4   658.7   365.5
2     587.5   987.5   478.6   658.5
3     987.1   542.6   986.2   458.7
```

The grid.dat contains the corresponding x values.

```
1     100.0   200.0   300.0   400.0
```

How can I plot with gnuplot the grid.dat as x values und a specific line of results.dat as corresponding y values? E.g. line 3:

```
1     100.0   987.1
2     200.0   542.6
3     300.0   986.2
4     400.0   458.7
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thats quite similar to the recent question [Gnuplot: plotting the maximum of two files](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19079146/2604213). In your case it is also not possible to do it with gnuplot only.

You need an external tool to combine the two files on-the-fly, e.g. with the following `python` script (any other tool would also do):

```py
""" selectrow.py: Select a row from 'results.dat' and merge with 'grid.dat'."""
import numpy as np
import sys

line = int(sys.argv[1])       

A = np.loadtxt('grid.dat')
B = np.loadtxt('results.dat', skiprows=(line-1))[0]

np.savetxt(sys.stdout, np.c_[A, B], delimiter='\t')
```

And then plot the third line of `results.dat` with

```
plot '< python selectrow.py 3' w l
```