# Performing calculations between multiple data files in gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

I have two data files with the same x axis data.  I would like to do some simple arithmetic over the y values in both data files and plot the result.  Is this possible without merging the files together first?

Comment: *I would like to do some computation over the y values*: Can you elaborate your question, please? Right now, the answer is yes and no. Some manipulation may be possible, however, do not expect too much.

Comment: @Schorsch I just want to take the difference of the two y values, or take a ratio between them, nothing more complex than that.

Comment: You can't do that directly in gnuplot, but you can merge the files on-the-fly, see [Get ratio from 2 files in gnuplot](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20069641/2604213).

Comment: @Christoph Thanks, I'll vote to close this as a duplication