# gnuplot: How do I plot a function of multiple files?

Tags: plot, gnuplot

I want to plot the following formula f = x+y, where x is a column from one file and y is a column from a different file.

Is this possible? How do I do it?

Comment: Does this help? https://www.ma.utexas.edu/users/ktaliaferro/gnuplot_examples.html#2var

Comment: You must merge the two files before you can do this, e.g. [Get ratio from 2 files in gnuplot](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20070138/2604213).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get ratio from 2 files in gnuplot](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20069641/get-ratio-from-2-files-in-gnuplot)

Answer (score 1):

Paste the files:

```
paste file1 file2 > file3
```

Then plot it:

```
plot "file3" u 1:($2+$4)
```

Or completely within gnuplot:

```
plot "< paste file1 file2" u 1:($2+$4)
```

where I assume that x was the second column in `file1` and y was the second column in `file2`: when pasted they will be columns 2 and 4, respectively.