# 3-Dimensional Plot in GnuPlot where color is a fourth column in my data file?

Tags: graph, colors, gnuplot, 4d

I have a datafile that looks like this:

```
1   2   3   0.5
2   8   9   0.2
3   4   78  0.4
6   5   7   0.01
9   9   9   0.3
10  12  18  0.9
6   8   4   1
```

I would like to do a graph like this
http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-378_rAaSSVU/UzU0gnGcr9I/AAAAAAAABnU/P1GwP9RKBkM/s1600/gnuplot.png
Where the 4th column is the color.

I tried - obviously incorrect because I do not use the fourth column but I failed to find anything in the documentation:

```
set dgrid3d 30,30
set view 60,45
set hidden3d
dataFile='prova.dat'
set palette defined (0 "blue", 0.5 "white", 1 "pink")
set pm3d 
splot dataFile u 1:2:3 with pm3d
```

Is somethings like that possible?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using only `pm3d` you can use a fourth column to select a color independent of the z-value. Together with `dgrid3d` this is not directly possible, because the gridding is not performed on the color column.

You can use a workaround: First you plot the gridded z-value to one file, then the gridded color values to a second file and as last point you disable `dgrid3d`, merge the two temporary files on-the-fly and plot their values:

```
set dgrid3d 30,30
dataFile='prova.dat'

set table dataFile.'.grid'
splot dataFile u 1:2:3
unset table

set table dataFile.'.color'
splot dataFile u 1:2:4
unset table

set view 60,45
set hidden3d
set palette defined (0 "blue", 0.5 "white", 1 "pink")
set autoscale cbfix
set pm3d
unset dgrid3d
set ticslevel 0
splot sprintf('< paste %s.grid %s.color', dataFile, dataFile) u 1:2:3:7 with pm3d notitle
```

[image]

Note, that `paste` is a command line tool for Unix-like operation systems. For a similar solution for windows, you can e.g. write a small Python script `paste.py` (see my answer to [Get ratio from 2 files in gnuplot](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20070138/2604213) for a possible implementation). Then you must run the `wgnuplot_pipes.exe` binary file and the `splot` command becomes

```
splot sprintf('< python paste.py %s.grid %s.color', dataFile, dataFile) u 1:2:3:7 with pm3d notitle
```

Of course, for this you must have python installed and the python binary must be available via the `PATH` environment variable.

Comment: Thank You for the swift answer.
I'm not a skilled user hence I do not understand -running the code with version 4.6 patchlevel 5- the warnings generated by the code:
line 19: warning: Skipping unreadable file "paste prova.dat.grid prova.dat.color"
line 19: warning: No usable data in this plot to auto-scale axis range
splot sprintf('paste %s.grid %s.color', dataFile, dataFile)
u 1:2:3:7 with pm3d notitle
                           ^
"C:\Users\Baroni\Desktop\prova.plt", line 19: All points x value undefined
I installed python and PATH, I created a script as yours linked but no progress

Comment: You must use the last command I wrote, with the `< python paste.py `...). The `<` is essential, and you must use the full name of your python script (propabaly `paste.py`).

Comment: I used past&copy so I suppose the problem is the absence of Gnuplot.py in my env, I'm trying to solve this problem.

Comment: No, you don't need Gnuplot.py! And according to your error message you didn't use copy & paste of the correct line. You must use the `splot` command I mentioned *after* the image: `splot sprintf('< python paste.py %s.grid %s.color', dataFile, dataFile) u 1:2:3:7 with pm3d notitle`.

Comment: Using Python with its PATH & Gnuplot, ther're this warnings: <code> line 19: warning: Skipping unreadable file "< python paste.py prova.dat.grid prova.dat.color"
         "C:\Users\Baroni\Desktop\prova.plt", line 19: warning: No usable data in this plot to auto-scale axis range

gnuplot> splot sprintf('< python paste.py %s.grid %s.color', dataFile, dataFile) u 1:2:3:7 with pm3d notitle
                                                                                                            ^
         "C:\Users\Baroni\Desktop\prova.plt", line 19: All points x value undefined </code>

Comment: Do you use `wgnuplot_pipes.exe`?

Comment: I'm sorry for the extended discussion (I've not enough reputation to instantiate a chat). I try to open -through Win Interface- the script py with Open with... wgnuplot_pipes.exe" but a window appears and disappears quickly and I'm not able to see anything.

Comment: If you want to see the result interactively, you should start `wgnuplot_pipes.exe` and then from the interactive gnuplot terminal run `load "script.gp"`, where the file `script.gp` contains all your plotting commands.

Comment: I do get an output from this code, but when I add gauss filtering to dgrid3d, the plot disappears.. any clue how to fix this?