# gnuplot, plotting 4D graph where colour is used to represent the 4th column

Tags: gnuplot, surface, 4d

My question is a continuation of: [3-Dimensional Plot in GnuPlot where color is a fourth column in my data file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25573139/3-dimensional-plot-in-gnuplot-where-color-is-a-fourth-column-in-my-data-file). I am trying to do basically the same thing with some data of mine. However, when I take the existing code and apply it to my text file, I get only get a surface at Z=0, and nowhere else. I have attached my graph [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PAXc0.png). I have data from z=[-80,80]. yet the data does not show up. Is there something wrong with the code?

```
set term png enhanced font "/usr/share/fonts/liberation/LiberationSans-Regular.ttf" 12 size 1024,960
set title "ADO-N1-4D"
set output "ADO-N1-4D.png"


set dgrid3d 30,30

dataFile='ADO-N1-his.txt'
set table dataFile.'.grid'
splot dataFile u 1:2:3
unset table

set table dataFile.'.color'
splot dataFile u 1:2:4
unset table

set view 60,45
set hidden3d

set palette defined (0 "white" , 0.5 "light-green"  ,1 "purple")
set autoscale cbfix
set pm3d
unset dgrid3d
set ticslevel 0
set xrange[2:9]
set yrange[-80:80]
set zrange[-80:80]

splot sprintf('< paste %s.grid %s.color', dataFile, dataFile) u 1:2:3:7 with pm3d notitle
```

sample data file is attached:

```
2.25000      -32.50000       20.00000        0.03965              1
2.25000      -12.50000        0.00000        0.04143              1
2.35000      -32.50000       20.00000        0.03642              1
2.35000       -7.50000        0.00000        0.03734              1
2.35000        2.50000        0.00000        0.03672              1
2.35000       12.50000       40.00000        0.03703              1
2.45000      -27.50000        0.00000        0.03356              1
2.45000      -27.50000       40.00000        0.03523              1
2.45000      -22.50000        0.00000        0.06821              2
2.45000      -17.50000        0.00000        0.03356              1
2.45000      -17.50000       20.00000        0.03552              1
2.45000      -12.50000       20.00000        0.03383              1
2.45000       -2.50000        0.00000        0.03438              1
2.45000       -2.50000       20.00000        0.03523              1
2.45000        2.50000       20.00000        0.03383              1
2.45000       32.50000       40.00000        0.03438              1
2.55000      -32.50000        0.00000        0.03151              1
2.55000      -27.50000        0.00000        0.12730              4
2.55000      -22.50000        0.00000        0.18983              6
2.55000      -17.50000      -20.00000        0.03201              1
2.55000      -17.50000        0.00000        0.06329              2
2.55000      -17.50000       20.00000        0.03303              1
2.55000      -12.50000        0.00000        0.12586              4
2.55000      -12.50000       20.00000        0.03176              1
2.55000       -7.50000      -20.00000        0.03251              1
2.55000       -7.50000        0.00000        0.31962             10
2.55000       -7.50000       20.00000        0.06352              2
2.55000       -2.50000      -20.00000        0.06230              2
2.55000       -2.50000        0.00000        0.15911              5
2.55000       -2.50000       20.00000        0.03103              1
2.55000        2.50000        0.00000        0.03277              1
2.55000        2.50000       20.00000        0.03201              1
2.55000       17.50000        0.00000        0.03127              1
2.65000      -42.50000        0.00000        0.02920              1
2.65000      -37.50000        0.00000        0.05951              2
2.65000      -32.50000      -40.00000        0.03010              1
2.65000      -32.50000      -20.00000        0.03056              1
2.65000      -32.50000        0.00000        0.09077              3
2.65000      -27.50000        0.00000        0.15004              5
2.65000      -22.50000      -20.00000        0.05820              2
2.65000      -22.50000        0.00000        0.05820              2
2.65000      -17.50000      -20.00000        0.08852              3
2.65000      -17.50000        0.00000        0.23617              8
2.65000      -17.50000       20.00000        0.11838              4
2.65000      -12.50000      -20.00000        0.08850              3
2.65000      -12.50000        0.00000        0.29542             10
2.65000      -12.50000       20.00000        0.11531              4
2.65000       -7.50000      -20.00000        0.09009              3
2.65000       -7.50000        0.00000        0.26670              9
2.65000       -7.50000       20.00000        0.05996              2
2.65000       -2.50000      -20.00000        0.05798              2
2.65000       -2.50000        0.00000        0.26619              9
2.65000       -2.50000       20.00000        0.03033              1
2.65000        2.50000        0.00000        0.11996              4
2.65000        2.50000       20.00000        0.02899              1
2.65000        7.50000       20.00000        0.03079              1
2.65000       22.50000       60.00000        0.02942              1
2.75000      -52.50000        0.00000        0.02695              1
2.75000      -37.50000        0.00000        0.08303              3
2.75000      -32.50000        0.00000        0.30819             11
2.75000      -27.50000      -40.00000        0.02856              1
2.75000      -27.50000      -20.00000        0.08246              3
2.75000      -27.50000        0.00000        0.08364              3
2.75000      -22.50000      -60.00000        0.02835              1
2.75000      -22.50000      -40.00000        0.02695              1
2.75000      -22.50000      -20.00000        0.11157              4
2.75000      -22.50000        0.00000        0.22231              8
2.75000      -22.50000       20.00000        0.05389              2
2.75000      -17.50000      -40.00000        0.02695              1
2.75000      -17.50000      -20.00000        0.08342              3
2.75000      -17.50000        0.00000        0.21875              8
2.75000      -17.50000       20.00000        0.13895              5
2.75000      -12.50000      -20.00000        0.24895              9
2.75000      -12.50000        0.00000        1.04906             38
2.75000      -12.50000       20.00000        0.27828             10
2.75000      -12.50000       40.00000        0.02675              1
2.75000       -7.50000      -20.00000        0.13573              5
2.75000       -7.50000        0.00000        0.46686             17
2.75000       -7.50000       20.00000        0.13830              5
2.75000       -2.50000      -40.00000        0.02695              1
2.75000       -2.50000      -20.00000        0.08321              3
2.75000       -2.50000        0.00000        0.41596             15
2.75000       -2.50000       20.00000        0.02774              1
2.75000        2.50000      -20.00000        0.02734              1
2.75000        2.50000        0.00000        0.13750              5
2.75000        2.50000       20.00000        0.02734              1
2.75000        7.50000      -20.00000        0.08124              3
2.75000        7.50000        0.00000        0.08362              3
2.75000       12.50000      -20.00000        0.02734              1
2.75000       12.50000        0.00000        0.02695              1
2.75000       17.50000       20.00000        0.02754              1
2.85000      -57.50000       60.00000        0.02619              1
2.85000      -42.50000      -40.00000        0.02656              1
2.85000      -37.50000        0.00000        0.02494              1
2.85000      -32.50000        0.00000        0.02601              1
2.85000      -27.50000      -20.00000        0.07803              3
2.85000      -27.50000       20.00000        0.02564              1
2.85000      -22.50000      -20.00000        0.07623              3
2.85000      -22.50000        0.00000        0.10349              4
2.85000      -22.50000       20.00000        0.05041              2
```

Comment: Have you double checked that you have data from -80 to 80 by removing the `set zrange` line? And have you double checked that this data is in the specified x and y range?

Comment: Yes, my data ranges are correct. It seems like the splot command is invoked on 1:2:3:7, which is strange to me. Is it calling an external file that it created in the process?

Comment: Are you sure, that the zrange still applies to the temporary files? If yes, you should make your data file available, otherwise we must keep on guessing.