# 4D plot with gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot, data-visualization, large-data, 4d

I have large data set arranged in four column in a file like this

```
# X Y Z f
0 0 0 0
1 0 0 0
2 0 0 0
3 0 0 0
4 0 0 0
5 0 0 0
6 0 0 0
7 0 0 0
...
```

where `(x,y,z)` is coordinate of each point in 3D mesh (between `[0,1]` in each direction and each direction divided into 256 interval) and `f` is the value of field at each point. I want to plot the data in a way that at each point, a colored circle, its color specified according to the value of `f` plotted. Since it is very large data set, the solution provided in [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25573439/11637575) does not work properly, and I have incorrect plot like this[image: p]

Comment: It looks like there is something special at the beginning of your data which confuses gnuplot. Maybe some header? How do the first few lines of your data look like?

Comment: I added first few lines of the data file. `# X Y Z f` is not exist in the file.I only added to make it clear which column correspond to which variable.

Comment: if your data starts like shown above then the data point at `(0,0,0)` looks ok. But if I don't have the data I cannot tell whether it is correct or not. So, you want to say that z should also be within `[0,1]`? Could you please describe exactly what you think is incorrect?

Comment: As I mentioned in the question the method suggested in [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25573439/11637575) does not work for my case. What I want to plot is at each `(x,y,z)` I want to plot small circle colored by `f` value. I do not know if it is possible in gnuplot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's still not clear to me what you exactly want to achieve and how your data really looks like.
Maybe it will get clearer with some minimal examples including *"full"* data.
Maybe something like this?

**Code:**

```
### splot with points and palette
reset session

$Data <<EOD
0 0 0 0.0
0 1 0 0.1
0 2 0 0.2
1 0 0 0.3
1 1 0 0.4
1 2 0 0.5
2 0 0 0.6
2 1 0 0.7
2 2 0 0.8
EOD

set palette rgb 33,13,10

splot $Data u 1:2:3:4 w p pt 7 ps 2 palette notitle
### end of code
```

**Result:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To make a suggestion about 4D plot in `gnuplot`, if you have very large dataset, `gnuplot` might not be a very appropriate option. Using [`paraview`](https://www.paraview.org/) is much better and give you more filters and tools to visualize your data. And it is also license-free software.