# gnuplot, multidimensional array, plotting, matrix,

Tags: arrays, matrix, multidimensional-array, plot, gnuplot

I am new to GNUPLOT and, I have encountered a problem which I do not know how to deal with. Any help from your side will be appreciated. The problem is:

I have two  files, say "A.dat" and "B. dat". Both are multidimensional array data. To be exact,

A.dat has 1000 rows and 100 columns. let row index be i from 1 to 1000, column index be k from 1 to 100.

B.dat has 1000 rows and 100 columns. let row index be i from 1 to 1000, column index be k from 1 to 100

I want to have a  two-dimensional plot, which has a total of k curves in it, 100 curves!

So, a given k-curve is drawn the coordinate axes, whose X coordinates are from A data and ,Y coordinates are from B data respectively.

So a k= 50 curve should be formed,  whose x values are the respective 50th column values of A.dat and, y values the respective 50th column values of B.dat. Also since for a total of 100 curves, I will like to have some sort of colour scale, like, k=1 be violet, k =100 be red.

Any idea on how to implement this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to plot your data, you must have x and y-values in a single file. The easiest way to get this is using e.g. the command line tool `paste` (or, if you are on Windows, use the `paste.py` script mentioned in [Get ratio from 2 files in gnuplot](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20070138/2604213)). Then you can plot them with

```
plot for [k=1:100] '< paste A.dat B.dat' using k:(column(k+100))
```

To get coloured lines you may define a custom color palette and use this with

```
set palette defined (0 'red', 1 'dark-violet')
plot for [k=1:100] '< paste A.dat B.dat' using k:(column(k+100)):(k) linecolor palette with lines notitle
```

Comment: many thanks for your trick. It worked, but not satisfactorily. I am attaching the outcome here.  http://postimg.org/image/f6cll0ayr/   How to get a better spectrum and also it seems picture is overpopulated with linetype symbols. I do not want them. I prefer just smooth curves and a colour palette showing the  magnitude of k.

Comment: I updated the answer, use `with lines` to get lines, `notitle` to omit the titles, and `linecolor palette` and a third column in the `using` statement to have the value of `k` on the colorbar.

Comment: For some reason, the data plotted with MatLaB looks fine, but GNUPLOT is not doing good. also it consumes much time.

Comment: The performance can be improved by generating a temporary file with `system('paste A.dat B.dat > C.dat')` and then plotting the file `C.dat` otherwise, the `paste` operation is done 100 times. About the "looks fine" I cannot say anything without concrete data files

Comment: I have always been a fan of GNUPLOT. to me the plots generated by gnuplot look cleaner. If you wish I can send the data files to you and the plots generated by Matlab and gnuplot. However let me try it myself first. And thanks again.

Comment: Yes, go ahead and let me know.

Comment: How do I send the data files to you. Do you have Matlab for reference?