# Ploting sum of data files gnuplot

Tags: plot, gnuplot

I have two really large data files and I need to plot the sum of theses files. Something like

```
plot "data1" + "data2" using 1:2
```

Is there a way I can do this using gnuplot?

I can't join the files by hand because they are really large (500mb)

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO! Please read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) post for how to ask better questions, which will help people give you better answers. In particular, add the code of what you've already tried.

Comment: Without knowing more about your data file, my best guess is `plot "< paste data1 data2" using 1:($2+$4)`, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/20070138/2604213. That assumes that your data files have two columns each with identical values in the first column.