# Gnuplot: How to plot the product of two columns from different files in one plot

Tags: plot, gnuplot

I have two files 'dat1.txt' and 'dat2.txt', each containing two columns of data.
Now, I want to plot column 1 from dat1.txt against the product of column 2 from dat1.txt and column 2 from dat2.txt such as:

`(column1 dat1):((column2 dat1)*(column2 dat2))`

I tried this by using:

`plot'< paste data1.txt data2.txt' using 1:($2*$4)`

which results in

`x range is invalid`

How is this possible using gnuplot?
Is there an easier way using a different program (e.g. mathematica)?

I guess, that I'm using **>paste** falsely or the range is not defined correctly.

Thanks.

Comment: The plot command looks fine, see also http://stackoverflow.com/a/20070138/2604213. If it doesn't work, it must be something you don't mention. How do your data files look like? Do you get any other error? Does your system have  `paste`? Etc

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your datafiles need a delimiter in the paste command:
`paste -d " " data1.txt data2.txt`