# Plotting arrows with start and end from two different files

Tags: gnuplot

I have two different .txt files with x and y coordinates of equal number of samples in both.

```
File 1
x y
1 2
5 4
4 6

File 2 
x y
5 6
3 4 
2 3
```

I want to connect each of these points inFile 1 with the corresponding points in File 2. I know to draw an arrow between two points it is

```
set arrow from (x,y) to (c,d)
```

But how do I get the coordinates of these points from two different files to draw connecting lines/ arrows?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20070138/2604213

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
plot "< paste file1.data file2.data" with vectors
```

Comment: +1, The `paste` command is certainly efficient if you are under Linux or if you have CoreUtils from GnuWin under Windows. But to be precise, this would not draw the OP's desired arrows, but `plot "< paste file1.data file2.data" u 1:2:($3-$1):($4-$2) with vectors` would.

Answer (score 0):

***Edit:** I came across this old answer and was amazed (actually shocked) how inefficient and complicated solutions I suggested.*

A much better approach: Since gnuplot 5.2.0 you can index datablocks. Prerequisite is that your data is in a datablock already. See here: [gnuplot: load datafile 1:1 into datablock](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54600172/7295599).
If you can be sure that your data files have identical number of lines, you can "mimic" the Linux `paste` command using a *gnuplot-only*, hence, *platform-independent* solution.

Basically, you join the two lines having the corresponding index after removing the last character (newline) of each line.

**Script:** (works with gnuplot>=5.2.0, Sept. 2017)

```
### plot arrows across two files, i.e. merge lines with gnuplot only
reset session

$Data1 <<EOD
File 1
x y
1 2
5 4
4 6
EOD

$Data2 <<EOD
File 2 
x y
5 6
3 4
2 3
EOD

set print $Combined
    do for [i=1:|$Data1|] {
        print $Data1[i][1:strlen($Data1[i])-1].' '.$Data2[i][1:strlen($Data2[i])-1]
    }
set print

plot $Combined u 1:2:($3-$1):($4-$2) w vec lc rgb "red"
### end of script
```

**Result:**

[image]