# How to connect points with different indices (one data file) in gnuplot

Tags: indexing, gnuplot, arrows

I have a file "a_test.dat" with two data blocks that I can select via the corresponding index.

```
# first
x1  y1
3   1
6   2
9   8

# second
x2  y2
4   5
8   2
2   7
```

Now I want to connect the data points of both indices with an arrow.

set arrow from (x1,y1) to (x2,y2).

I can plot both blocks with one plot statement. But I cannot get the points to set the arrows.

plot "a_test.dat" index "first" u 1:2, "" index "second" u 1:2

Comment: Do you have _one_ or _two_ blank lines as separation? If you want to address (sub)blocks via `index` the separation should be *two* empty lines. So, as I understand you want to draw an arrow from 3,1 to 4,5 and from 6,2, to 8,2, etc., correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From version 5.2 you can use gnuplot arrays:

```
stats "a_test.dat" nooutput
array xx[STATS_records]
array yy[STATS_records]
# save all data into two arrays
i = 1
fnset(x,y) = (xx[i]=x, yy[i]=y, i=i+1)
# parse data ignoring output
set table $dummy
plot "" using (fnset($1,$2)) with table
unset table
# x2,y2 data starts at midpoint in array
numi = int((i-1)/2)

plot for [i=1:numi] $dummy using (xx[i]):(yy[i]):(xx[numi+i]-xx[i]):(yy[numi+i]-yy[i]) with vectors
```

Use `stats` to count the number of lines in the file, so that the array can
be large enough. Create an array `xx` and another `yy` to hold the data.
Use `plot ... with table` to read the file again, calling your function
`fnset()` for each data line with the x and y column values. The function
saves them at the current index `i`, which it increments. It was
initialised to 1.

For 3+3 data lines, `i` ends up at 7, so we set `numi` to `(i-1)/2` i.e. 3.
Use `plot for ... vectors` to draw the arrows. Each arrow needs 4 data
items from the array. Note that the second x,y must be a relative delta,
not an absolute position.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Another solution with gnuplot only. Of course, you could also use external tools to modify your data, but if possible, I prefer gnuplot-only solutions, since they are *platform-independent*. It is basically the same principle like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53731790/7295599).

The following script works independent if your subdatablocks are separated by **one** or **two** empty lines.

**Data:** `SO75483386.dat`

```
# first
x1  y1
3   1
6   2
9   8

# second
x2  y2
4   5
8   2
2   7
```

**Script:** (requires gnuplot>=5.2.0, because of indexing of datablocks)

```
### combine lines of different subblocks into one line
reset session

FILE = "SO75483386.dat"

set table $Temp
    plot FILE u 1:2 w table
unset table

set print $Data
    N = |$Temp|/2
    do for [i=1:N] { 
        print $Temp[i]."   ".$Temp[i+N]
    }
unset print
print $Data

set offsets 1,1,1,1

plot $Data u 1:2:($3-$1):($4-$2):0 w vec lc var lw 2 notitle
### end of script
```

**Result:**

```
 3       1          4    5      
 6       2          8    2      
 9       8          2    7
```

[image]