# How to create hypertext arrows in gnuplot?

Tags: gnuplot, hidden, arrows

How can I create hypertext-like vectors or arrows that only appear when the user places the mouse on or near the start/end points?
For points it looks like this:

```
indices = "first second"

plot for [id in indices] "a_test.dat" index id u 1:2

replot for [i=1:words(indices)] "a_test.dat" index word( indices, i ) u 1:2:(sprintf("point = (%d, %d)", column(1), column(2))) w labels hypertext point pt 7 ps 2 lc rgb '#ff000000' notitle
```

File "a_test.dat":

```
# first
x1  y1
5   1
6   2
9   8

# second
x2  y2
4   5
8   2
2   7
```

Comment: I don't think gnuplot can do that. What terminal type are you using? You can make the `hypertext` option popup an image from a file, which could provide a separately generated plot with the wanted arrow.

Comment: I am using gnuplot-qt 5.4. How to display an image with 'hypertext'? Does that mean creating a new plot with just a single arrow? If that works it would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you can mimic a "hypertext arrow" with a `while` loop and `pause mouse`.

For vectors it is better to have start/endpoints in one line, but that is a different topic. I will think about an answer about [your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75483386/7295599).
Here, for simplicity, it is assumed that you have the start/endpoints already in one line.

- the data is plotted once and then you enter a `while` loop (check `help while`) which you can stop by pressing `ESC`.
- when button 1 of the mouse is pressed, the data is plotted again, but additionally, the dataline with the minimal distance to the mouse position (i.e. variables `MOUSE_X` and `MOUSE_Y`) is plotted `with vectors`. However, it seems you can't use `MOUSE_X` and `MOUSE_Y` in a function. So, well, then your have to assign it first to variables `x0` and `y0`.
- you could probably tune the behaviour of the appearance of the arrow, i.e. whether it disappears after some time or if you move on, etc...)

**Script:** (tested with gnuplot 5.4.1 and wxt and qt terminals)

```
### show arrow on mouse button press (mimic hypertext arrow)
reset session

$Data <<EOD
# first   # second
x1  y1    x2  y2
5   1     4   5
6   2     8   2
9   8     2   7
EOD

set offsets 1,1,1,1
set key out noautotitle

plot $Data u 1:2 w p pt 7 ps 2 lc "blue" ti "start point", \
        '' u 3:4 w p pt 7 ps 2 lc "red"  ti "end point"

dist(colX,colY) = sqrt((column(colX)-x0)**2 + (column(colY)-y0)**2)

continue = 1
while (continue) {
    pause mouse button1,keypress
    if (MOUSE_KEY == 27) { continue=0 }   # press ESC to stop loop
    else {
        x0 = MOUSE_X
        y0 = MOUSE_Y
        plot dMin=NaN \
            $Data u (d=dist(1,2), (dMin!=dMin || d<dMin)?(dMin=d,idxMin=$0):0,$1):2 skip 1 \
                w p pt 7 ps 2 lc "blue" ti "start point", \
            '' u (d=dist(3,4), d<dMin?(dMin=d,idxMin=$0):0,$3):4 w p pt 7 ps 2 lc "red"  ti "end point", \
            '' u 1:2:($3-$1):($4-$2) every ::idxMin::idxMin skip 1 w vec lw 2 lc black
    }
}
### end of script
```

**Screen capture:** (from wxt terminal)

[image]

**Addition:** (keep and remove arrows)

Here is a version where you keep several arrows and you can remove them by clicking again close to their start/endpoint. You can remove all arrows at once if you do a right mouse click (on my system this is `MOUSE_BUTTON==3`).

- define a string `arrowIdxs`containing the selected arrows, i.e. line indices
- define a function `inList()` which checks if an index is in the list
- define a function `updateList()` which either adds a new index or removes an index if it was already in the list.

I hope you can figure out yourself how the script works in detail.
Check `help <keyword>` for the following used keywords: `sprintf`, `sum`, `strstrt`, `strlen`.

**Script:**

```
### show/hide arrows on mouse button click
reset session

$Data <<EOD
# first   # second
x1  y1    x2  y2
5   1     4   5
6   2     8   2
9   8     2   7
EOD

set offsets 1,1,1,1
set key out noautotitle

plot $Data u 1:2 w p pt 7 ps 2 lc "blue" ti "start point", \
        '' u 3:4 w p pt 7 ps 2 lc "red"  ti "end point"

dist(colX,colY) = sqrt((column(colX)-x0)**2 + (column(colY)-y0)**2)

arrowIdxs = ''
inList(list,n)     = (_s=sprintf("%d",n), int(sum[_i=1:words(list)] word(list,_i) eq _s))
updateList(list,n) = (_s=sprintf("%d",n), inList(list,n) ? \
      list[1:strstrt(list,_s)-2].list[strstrt(list,_s)+strlen(_s):] : list.' '.sprintf("%d",n))

continue = 1
while (continue) {
    pause mouse button1,button3,keypress
    if (MOUSE_KEY == 27) { continue=0 }   # press ESC to stop loop
    else {
        mb=MOUSE_BUTTON
        if (mb==1) {
            x0 = MOUSE_X
            y0 = MOUSE_Y
            plot dMin=NaN \
                $Data u (d=dist(1,2), (dMin!=dMin || d<dMin)?(dMin=d,idxMin=$0):0,$1):2 skip 1 \
                    w p pt 7 ps 2 lc "blue" ti "start point", \
                '' u (d=dist(3,4), d<dMin?(dMin=d,idxMin=$0):0,$3):4 w p pt 7 ps 2 lc "red"  ti "end point", \
                arrowIdxs = updateList(arrowIdxs,idxMin) \
                '' u (inList(arrowIdxs,$0)? $1:NaN):2:($3-$1):($4-$2) skip 1 w vec lw 2 lc black
        }
        if (mb==3) {
            arrowIdxs = ''
            plot $Data u 1:2 w p pt 7 ps 2 lc "blue" ti "start point", \
                    '' u 3:4 w p pt 7 ps 2 lc "red"  ti "end point"
        }
    }
}
### end of script
```

**Screen capture:** (from wxt terminal)

[image]

Comment: How could I clear all arrows when the right mouse button is clicked?

Comment: @magfan what do mean with "all arrows"? The script is only plotting one arrow. Do you maybe want to keep all the selected arrows? And clear them all with a right mouse click?

Comment: I always assumed a single arrow because I was thinking of hypertext and hovering. But marking multiple arrows is indeed a very interesting option.

Comment: @magfan see modified answer which I guess is now pretty versatile.

Comment: I used the code once with original data. There is a problem with determining the distance of the mouse from the start or end point. In most cases, a different vector than expected is displayed - far away from the cursor's position. Original data look like (one line : int float int float): 1       1979.2  2       2027 
 1       1598.6  2       1591.4
 1       1430.8  2       1401.6
 1       1544.7  2       1923.7
 1       1953.3  2       1677
 1       1288.8  2       1311.1
 1       1741.3  2       1689.3
 1       1791.1  2       2015.8

Comment: @magfan ok, I see the issue. This is because with your real data x-axis and y-axis are different by several orders of magnitude. Hence, the calculated distances are different compared to the visual distances you see on the screen. Well, then you have to use graph or screen coordinates instead. As soon as I will find some time I will add that option.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is possible, almost.  But you wouldn't use hypertext, you'd use the "toggle plot" functionality.  I will show a complete script below, but here's the basic idea:

Draw a graph that contains (plot 1) the tail points (plot 2) the head points (plots 3 to N) a separate plot for each arrow.  Because each arrow is in a separate plot it can be toggled on/off by clicking on its title.  The `toggle` commands in the script turn the arrows off to start with. Now we get to the tricky part.  Instead of letting the title be placed automatically in the key box for the graph, we explicitly position each title ***on top of its tail point***.  Now you can click on the point and voila, the arrow appears.

Here is the script

```
set xrange [0:10]
set yrange [0:10]
set style arrow 1 head nofill lc "black"

# Here is the data
$ARROWS << EOF
x1  y1  x2  y2    
5   1   4   5     
6   2   8   2     
9   8   2   7     
EOF

#
# This is the basic plot, with everything visible.
# In an interactive terminal (qt/wxt/x11/windows/svg) you can toggle
# the arrows on and off by clicking on the corresponding title in the key.
#

set key samplen 0.01

plot $ARROWS using 1:2 with points pt 7 ps 2 title "Click me", \
     $ARROWS using 3:4 with points pt 7 ps 2 notitle, \
     for [i=1:*] $ARROWS every 1::i::i using 1:2:($3-$1):($4-$2) with vectors as 1 title " "

pause -1

#
# Now we get tricky by placing the arrow titles on top of the points
# rather than in the key, and we programmatically toggle off the arrows.
# You should be able to make the arrow appear by clicking on the point
# that corresponds to the arrow tail.
#

array tx[3]
array ty[3]
do for [i=1:3] {
    tx[i] = int(word($ARROWS[i+1],1))
    ty[i] = int(word($ARROWS[i+1],2))
}

plot $ARROWS using 1:2 with points pt 7 ps 2 title "Click me", \
     $ARROWS using 3:4 with points pt 7 ps 2 notitle, \
     for [i=1:3] $ARROWS every 1::i::i using 1:2:($3-$1):($4-$2) with vectors as 1 \
        title " " at first tx[i], first ty[i]

do for [plot=3:5] {toggle plot}

pause -1
```

Here is a screen shot of the plot before the first click
[image]

And here is a screen show of the plot after clicking on one of the points
[image]

I say this is "almost" possible because I had to use a very clunky separate step to load the title coordinates into arrays.  It would be much cleaner to generate them on the fly as the plot is drawn. I don't think that is possible currently, though maybe I am missing some clever trick.

Answer (score 0):

Extending on my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75495509/5008284) to your previous question, this is the sort of thing you can do with hypertext image:

[image: screen snapshot]

This is a screen snapshot of an svg file with the (yellow) cursor hovering above the point (4,5). The svg viewer (in this case, my browser) has popped up the small image with the purple arrow from the file `/tmp/fig1.png` on my system. It may not be exactly what you want, but it's the best I can do with gnuplot. Here's the code:

```
set term png size 400, 400   linewidth 3
unset key
stats "a_test.dat" nooutput
array xx[STATS_records]
array yy[STATS_records]
set xrange [STATS_min_x:STATS_max_x]
set yrange [STATS_min_y:STATS_max_y]
set offsets graph 0.05, graph 0.05, graph 0.05, graph 0.05
# save all data into two arrays
i = 1
fnset(x,y) = (xx[i]=x, yy[i]=y, i=i+1)
set table $dummy
 plot "" using (fnset($1,$2)) with table
unset table
numi = int((i-1)/2)

#-----create fig*.png files
do for [i=1:numi] {
  set output "/tmp/fig".i.".png"
  plot for [j=i:i] $dummy using (xx[j]):(yy[j]):(xx[numi+j]-xx[j]):(yy[numi+j]-yy[j]) with vectors
  set output
}

#-----2nd part

set term svg  size 400, 400  mouse standalone   linewidth 3
set output "aaa.svg"

indices = "first second"
count=0
fncount(x,y)=(count=(count==numi?1:count+1),count)
plot for [i=1:words(indices)] "a_test.dat" \
 index word( indices, i ) \
 u 1:2:(sprintf("image:/tmp/fig%d.png\nfig",fncount($1,$2) )) \
 w labels hypertext point pt 7 ps 2  notitle
```

I won't explain the lines that are from the previous answer, such as
reading the data into the 2 arrays `xx` and `yy`. To keep the same scale
for all the graphs, it is explicitly set using `set xrange ...` to min and
max calculated from the statistics command.

The first part of the code uses `do for` to create files `fig1.png` and so
on, each showing just one arrow, using one set of 4 data items from the arrays.

The second part selects the `svg` terminal type, with option `mouse` and
`standalone`. This inserts the JavaScript needed to handle the mouse popup into
the svg output file. The `plot` command is based on your example, with the 3rd column
of data being, for example, the string "image:/tmp/fig1.png\nfig" for the
first set of data. The function `fncount()` just increments on each call,
from 1 to 3 (if you have 3 lines of data per block), then back to 1. This
re-uses the same 3 image files at the start and end data points.

Note that the svg viewer must be able to find the image files in the filesystem.